# Obtain ValueError and Out of range at the same time?

Tags: python

```
def open_file():
'''Repeatedly prompt until a valid file name allows the file to be opened.'''
    while True:
        year_str = input("Enter a year where 1990 <= year <= 2015: ")
        file_name = ("year" + year_str + ".txt")
        if int(year_str) <= 2015 and int(year_str) >= 1990:
            try:
                fp = open(file_name,'r')
                return fp
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error in file name: " + file_name + ". Please try again.")
                open_file()
        else:
            print("Error in year. Please try again.")
            open_file()
```

The above is my code. I am supposed to open a file in range(1990,2016). The test I am gonna go through is when I typed 'xxxx' or year that is out of range, it will print

```
Error in year. Please try again
```

However, when I ran my code, python showed that

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xxxx'
```

I thought the else statement could handle the value error and out of range at the same time. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers here missed something important - you get the error during your `int(year_str)` statement but everybody here offered you to add a `try...except` block when opening the file. That doesn't help you.

What you need is this:

```
def open_file():
'''Repeatedly prompt until a valid file name allows the file to be opened.'''
    while True:
        year_str = input("Enter a year where 1990 <= year <= 2015: ")
        file_name = ("year" + year_str + ".txt")
        try:
            year_int = int(year_str)
        except ValueError:
            print("Error in year. Please try again.")
            continue # to try again within your loop
        if year_int <= 2015 and year_int >= 1990:
            try:
                fp = open(file_name,'r')
                return fp
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error in file name: " + file_name + ". Please try again.")
        else:
            print("Error in year. Please try again.")

open_file()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
def open_file():
    """ Repeatedly prompt until a valid file name allows the file to be opened."""
    while True:
        year_str = input("Enter a year where 1990 <= year <= 2015: ")
        file_name = ("year" + year_str + ".txt")
        if int(year_str) <= 2015 and int(year_str) >= 1990:
            try:
                fp = open(file_name, 'r')
                return fp
            except IOError:
                print("Error in file name: " + file_name + ". Please try again.")
                open_file()
        else:
            print("Error in year. Please try again.")

open_file()
```

Note that docstring in python should be written with triple double quotes.

There is no `FileNotFoundError` exception in python2 It is present in python3. You can use IOError when you need to catch file not found exceptions in python2.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to handle all types of exceptions other than `FileNotFoundError` by a generic handle block, then you can change your `else` statement to a generic `except` block

```
def open_file():
'''Repeatedly prompt until a valid file name allows the file to be opened.'''
    while True:
        year_str = input("Enter a year where 1990 <= year <= 2015: ")
        file_name = ("year" + year_str + ".txt")
        if int(year_str) <= 2015 and int(year_str) >= 1990:
            try:
                fp = open(file_name,'r')
                return fp
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error in file name: " + file_name + ". Please try again.")
                open_file()
            except Exception:
                print("Error in year. Please try again.")

open_file()
```

Edit 1:
If you wish to get the error message from the exception, you can give it a name while catching like:

```
except Exception as e:
    print('Error occured: %s' % e)
```